# SonarQube Error During Runner Execution

Tags: sonarqube, socket-timeout-exception

I am new to SonarQube and was having a connection timed out error preventing sonar-runner from publishing a small application to sonarqube.

Versions:

- SonarQube Runner 2.4
- Java 1.7.0_45 Oracle Corporation (64-bit)
- Linux 3.5.0-42-generic amd64

The confusing part is that this works fine when executing sonar-runner on the windows machine hosting sonarqube. I have changed the port default port from 9000 and tested both connections for validity. That has not resolved the issue.

Only when attempting to run sonar-runner manually from the command line on the virtual machine storing the source code does and error occur. I have also increased the allowable memory in the heap size via the SONAR_RUNNER_OPTS in the sonar-runner.bat file.

Please advise or let me know what additional information is needed.

```
INFO: Error stacktraces are turned on. 
INFO: Runner configuration file: /opt/sonar-runner/sonar-runner-2.4/conf/sonar-runner.properties 
INFO: Project configuration file: /var/lib/svn/repos/secureci/secureciDemoRepo/LaserGem_Sample/sonar-project.properties 
INFO: Default locale: "en_US", source code encoding: "UTF-8" 
INFO: Work directory: /var/lib/svn/repos/secureci/secureciDemoRepo/LaserGem_Sample/./.sonar 
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE 
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
Total time: 30.047s Final Memory: 0M/30M 
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution org.sonar.runner.kevinsawicki.HttpRequest$HttpRequestException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
 at org.sonar.runner.kevinsawicki.HttpRequest.code(HttpRequest.java:1392)
 at org.sonar.runner.kevinsawicki.HttpRequest.ok(HttpRequest.java:1417)
 at org.sonar.runner.impl.ServerConnection.downloadString(ServerConnection.java:93)
 at org.sonar.runner.impl.ServerVersion.downloadVersion(ServerVersion.java:47)
 at org.sonar.runner.impl.ServerVersion.version(ServerVersion.java:38)
 at org.sonar.runner.impl.ServerVersion.is37Compatible(ServerVersion.java:58)
 at org.sonar.runner.impl.JarDownloader.checkVersionAndDownload(JarDownloader.java:36)
 at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:71)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
 at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
 at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102)
 at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:100)
 at org.sonar.runner.Main.executeTask(Main.java:70)
 at org.sonar.runner.Main.execute(Main.java:59)
 at org.sonar.runner.Main.main(Main.java:53) Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1675)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1673)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(HttpURLConnection.java:1671)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1244)
 at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:468)
 at org.sonar.runner.kevinsawicki.HttpRequest.code(HttpRequest.java:1390) ... 15 more Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
 at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
 at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
 at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
 at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
 at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
 at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
 at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)
 at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
 at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
 at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:211)
 at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308)
 at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:996)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:932)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:850)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1300)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getHeaderField(HttpURLConnection.java:2678)
 at org.sonar.runner.kevinsawicki.HttpRequest.header(HttpRequest.java:1903)
 at org.sonar.runner.kevinsawicki.HttpRequest.contentType(HttpRequest.java:2308)
 at org.sonar.runner.impl.ServerConnection.downloadString(ServerConnection.java:89) ... 13 more
```

Comment: Did you find out the solution to this? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: The issue was networking related. The SonarQube server could be reached, but much of the communications were blocked. The red herring was ping. I was confident the system was communicating properly because I could ping SonarQube from the system containing the source code, and vice versa. However, using traceroute highlighted the problem that most of the communications were blocked. This was a firewall issue.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like your Linux server on which you try to run the SonarQube analysis cannot reach the Windows server on which the SonarQube server runs. You might have some firewall or network settings that prevents this communication.

Comment: Thank you. Ping was able to hit the SonarQube from the development server, and vice versa, but traceroute failed. Resolving the networking issue has allowed the tool to progress.